# TextFormField in listview is not able to retain value on list refresh upon button click in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have a listview with TextFormField. I can add/remove these values on button click. Some of the data in the list is already there when it is created. It is updated from an array. But when I enter any new data in the new TextFormField and press any button the data is lost from the TextFormField. Although I am assinging it in the array source and updating state. Folllowing is the list:

```
    Widget taxInfoListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: taxResidencyList.length,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => TaxDetailItem(
        taxResidence: taxResidencyList[index],
        textEditingController: controllers[index],
        countrySelectionChanged: getUpdatedCountryCode,
        index: index,
        taxCountryRemove: removeTaxCountry,
        isError: (errorIndex == index) ? true : false,
      ),
    );
  }
```

ListItem code:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    textEditingController.value = TextEditingValue(text: taxResidence.id);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            'WHICH COUNTRY SERVES AS YOUR PRIMARY TAX RESIDENCE?*',
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          ModalDropDownButton(
            selectedItem: searchByCountryCode(),
            items: getCountryListItems(),
            searchItemHint: 'Search for Country',
            itemSelectionChanged: countrySelectionChanged,
            listitemIndex: index,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Text('TAX IDENTIFICATION NUMBER*',
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40.0,
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 5),
                  hintText: 'Tax ID or N/A'),
              controller: textEditingController,
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(visible: isError, child: Text('Please enter Tax id and select country', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red) )),
          index > 0 ? Row(
            children: [
              Spacer(),
              ElevatedButton(style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                elevation: 0,
                side: BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.white),
              ), onPressed: () => {
                taxCountryRemove(index)
              },
                  child: Text('-REMOVE', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),))
            ],
          ) : Container()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Following is how I manage state:

```
    Widget addMoreTaxCountry() {
    return Row(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              elevation: 0,
              side: const BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              myBloc.add(OnAddTaxCountryEvent());
            },
            child: Text(
              '+ ADD ANOTHER',
              style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            )),
        const Spacer()
      ],
    );
  }
BlocListener<TaxDetailBloc, TaxDetailState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
if (state is AddNewTaxCountryState) {
              taxResidencyList.add(state.taxResidence);
              TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
              controllers.add(controller);
              setState(() {});
            }
}
```

Comment: im just quick reading your code. `textEditingController.value = TextEditingValue(text: taxResidence.id);` you override the value on every widget rebuild. ``TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();` you replace the controller with a new on every `BlocListener` event.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the TextFormField with the desired value or the input itself when the state changes.
Also, if you can separate this TextFormField's state from the triggering one, it will be easier ,maintain.

Comment: Could you please give me an example? Didn't understand, sorry I am bit new to Flutter